# AWS Chalice using custom config path or custom app path?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, chalice

I am trying to use Chalice to fit into an pre-existing build folder structure, the python source file (app.py) is one level deeper than the vanilla Chalice project

```
├── .chalice
│   └── config.json
└── src
    ├── app.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── requirements_test.txt
```

When I run `chalice local` in `src` folder it says it cannot find the config file:

```
Unable to load the project config file. Are you sure this is a chalice project?
```

When I run `chalice local` in the project folder, it says it cannot find the source file:

```
No module named 'app'
```

I had a look at the config file doesn't seem to have an option to specify where the source file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were no responses on Stackoverflow, so I went to the project and opened an issue [ticket](https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/622) for it, from the horses mouth, this is not possible at this stage.